# How to export a table with row names from Matlab to Excel?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to export a table from Matlab to Excel with the names of the rows. Here is a (very) simplified version of my table:

```
T = table(1,5,2);
T.Properties.RowNames = {'Number'}

T = 

          Var1    Var2    Var3
          ____    ____    ____

Number    1       5       2
```

If I apply Matlab's [instructions for exporting a table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/exporting-to-excel-spreadsheets.html):

```
filename = 'data.xlsx';
writetable(T,filename,'Sheet',1,'Range','D1')
```

it leaves out my row name "Number" and only exports the variables:

```
Var1    Var2    Var3
____    ____    ____

1       5       2
```

Is there a way to export a table **including** row names from Matlab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `WriteRowNames` optional input

`writetable(T,filename,'Sheet',1,'Range','D1','WriteRowNames',true)`